# converting time to POSIXct in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that can have values like this:

```
p<-c("2012-08-14 9:00", "2012-08-14 7:00:00")
```

I am trying to conver to datetime as this:

```
p<-as.POSIXct(p)

this converted everyting to to 2012-08-14 09:00:00
```

for some reason, it is not working anymore. If you have noticed, my data sometimes have seconds and somtimes it does not.
How do you force this to be datetime format?

I get errors like this:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(p) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: take a look at `?strptime` for the arguments, but you need to include something like `as.POSIXct(p, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')`

Comment: @justin, this does not work either: as.POSIXct(p, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work?  This works great for me with the `p` vector you supplied.  Please post the error you get.  Also, can you use `dput(p)` so we can see the whole thing?  I assume you have dates with multiple different formats which will take some munging to fix.

Comment: I used strptime and that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your vector isn't in a consistent format, so convert it to `POSIXlt` first because `as.POSIXlt.character` checks multiple formats.

```
p <- c("2012-08-14 9:00", "2012-08-14 7:00:00")
plt <- as.POSIXlt(p)
pct <- as.POSIXct(plt)
```

Comment: +1 that's slick... I've always regexed timestamp strings until `POSIXct` will take em.

Answer (score 0):

the package lubridate may help
here an example - perhaps not the most elegant one - but it hs

```
p<-c("2012-08-14 9:00", "2012-08-14 7:00:00")

require(lubridate) # 


NewDate <- c()
for (i in 1 : 2)
        {
          if (nchar(unlist(strsplit(p[i], ' '))[2]) == 4) {NewDate <- c(NewDate,       as.character(ymd_hm(p[i])))}
          if (nchar(unlist(strsplit(p[i], ' '))[2]) == 7) {NewDate <- c(NewDate, as.character(ymd_hms(p[i])))}
        }
NewDate
```